# How to make a for loop in Jinja?

Tags: jinja2

I want to make a **for-loop** that goes from 0 to 10 in **Jinja**.

How do I do it?

Comment: This [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198334/jinja2-and-for-loop) might help.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can create a loop like this:

```
{% for i in range(11) %}
  {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```