# How to code in Flask a For In Loop iterating through lists to create new page links?

Tags: python, html, flask, nested-lists

Learning Flask and I'm stuck trying to create a for loop that iterates over each element in the list of cars. I need to concatenate this to html so that if I navigate to each page for the <car_type>s, I can see the lists of cars and their features. This may be really simple but somehow I cant seem to make it work.

I want it to look like this;
If I go to the pickups page link <.../cars/pickups>
List of Pickups

- Color: green
- Mileage: 23000
- Color: silver
- Mileage: 40000

If I go to the Sedans page link <.../cars/sedans>
List of Sedans

- color: black
- mileage: 10000

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from dict import cars

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return f'''
  <h1>Buy a Car!</h1>
  <p>Browse through the links below to find your new mean machine:</p>
  <ul>
  <li>Pickups</li>
  <li>Sedans</li>
  <li>Trucks</li>
  </ul>
  '''

@app.route('/cars/<car_type>')
def car_list(car_type):
  html = f'<h1>List of {car_type}</h1>'
  for car_type in cars.keys():
    html += cars[Pickups], cars[Sedans],cars[Trucks]
  return html
```

Here is the code for the dictionary in a different python file(dict.py):

```
cars = {
    'Pickups': [
        {
            'color': 'green',
            'mileage': 23000,
        },
        {
            'color': 'silver',
            'mileage': 40000,
             }
    ],
    'Sedans': [
        {
            'color': 'black',
            'mileage': 10000,
        }
    ],
    'Trucks': [
        {
            'colors': 'sky blue',
            'mileage': 43000,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you show an example of the expected result or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your app needs to be built from scratch. A lot of mistakes. You must need to create a jinja loop inside your html file in order to get what you want. 
See here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706099/how-to-make-a-for-loop-in-jinja
Also, in your cars route, <li> tags must include links (<a> tags) to cars/types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for listing one type of cars.

```py
@app.route('/cars/<car_type>')
def list_car_type(car_type):
    html = f'<h1>List of {car_type}</h1><ul>'
    for car in cars[car_type]:
        for key, value in car:
            html += f'<li>{key.capitalize()}: {value}</li>
    html += '</ul>'
    return html
```