# How import a csv file from a webpage using flask?

Tags: python, excel, csv, flask, import

How to import a csv file from a webpage using python-flask, in webpage you just browse your file and click import and show the content of file in a table(webpage). just like that not import to the database. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [How to build up a HTML table with a simple for loop in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204987/8916412)

```
<table>
{% for item in items %}
<TR>
   <TD class="c1">{{item.var1}}</TD>
   <TD class="c2">{{item.var2}}</TD>
   <TD class="c3"><SPAN>{{item.var3}}</SPAN></TD>
   <TD class="c4"><SPAN>{{item.var4}}</SPAN></TD>
</TR>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Just pass your csv extracted content in `items` variable like this:

```
return render_template('page.html', items=items)
```

In this example, I assume that each `item` is an instance of the class:

```
class Item:
   def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4):
       self.var1 = var1
       self.var2 = var2
       self.var3 = var3
       self.var4 = var4
```