# Building a dynamic table with jinja2, html and flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

```
<table style="width:100%", border="1">
        {% for item in items %}    
        <tr>               
            <td>{{Description[item]}}</td>
            <td>{{Location[item]}}</td>
            <td>{{Status[item]}}</td>                
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}    
</table>
```

I am trying to create a table using this for loop, the variables are being passed through in the flask framework, 'items' will always be the same length as the three lists (Description, location and status).
I am aware of the question below:
[How to build up a HTML table with a simple for loop in Jinja2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198334/how-to-build-up-a-html-table-with-a-simple-for-loop-in-jinja2)

but I can not see how my code here differs to the working answer to this question, is it because I am using a list instead of a dictionary ?

This is the flask framework, where the lists
are created an passed through using render template:

```
def index():
description = []
location = []
status = []
imix80m = ''
imix = ''
with open('behavepretty.json') as a:
    data = json.load(a)
    for n in range(0,len(data)):
        i = 0
        for i in range(0, len(data[n]['elements'])):
            x = data[n]['elements'][i]['name']
            description.append(x)
            y = data[n]['elements'][i]['location']
            location.append(y)
            z = data[n]['elements'][i]['status']
            status.append(z)
        n = 0
    for n in range(0,len(data)):
        if n == 0:
            imix80m = data[n]['status']
        elif n == 1:
            imix = data[n]['status']
a.close()
return render_template('trial.html', Description = description, Location= location, Status = status, result1 = imix80m, result2 = imix, jfile = data, items = description)
```

Comment: Post the view code (python).  Were are `Description`, `Location`, `Status` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a loop counter:

```
<table style="width:100%", border="1">
        {% for item in Description %}    
        <tr>               
            <td>{{Description[loop.index0 ]}}</td>
            <td>{{Location[loop.index0]}}</td>
            <td>{{Status[loop.index0]}}</td>                            
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}    
</table>
```

Or, you could pack the 3 into a list of lists:

```
my_list = [[Description0, Location0, Status0], [Description1, Location1, Status1], ...]
```

Then:

```
    {% for item in my_list %}    
        <tr>               
            <td>{{ item[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item[2] }}</td>                            
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Or, more robustly, a list of dictionaries:

```
my_list = [
    {
        "description" : xxx, 
        "location" : yyy, 
        "status" : zzz
    },
    {
        "description" : www, 
        "location" : eee, 
        "status" : rrr
    },
    ...
]
```

Then:

```
    {% for item in my_list %}    
        <tr>               
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.location }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.status }}</td>                            
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: description, location and status are all individual lists being passed through from the flask framework, items is just used as a counter, should I combine the three lists into one dictionary ?

Comment: What is `items`?  Is that a list you are passing?  Maybe you are just looking for a loop counter.  I will edit the answer, but you need to post the python code

Comment: posted python, yes I was just using it as a loop counter

Comment: does 'forloop.counter' need to be defined somewhere or is this built in recognition ?

Comment: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'forloop' is undefined, receiving this error message @GAEfan

Comment: Sorry, that is from Django.  I will update for Flask ... Make sure you use `loop.index0` if you want to start from 0 (you do).

Comment: I just added a couple of other approaches to consider.  The list of dictionaries is more robust, and easier to follow in the future, or if you add properties.